# Aggregation over order-dependent partition?

Tags: sql, select, aggregate-functions

I have a source data set like this (simplified to be more clear):

```
Key  F1  F2
1    X   4
2    X   5
3    Y   6
4    X   9
5    X   7
6    X   8
7    Y   9
8    X   6
9    X   5
10   Y   3
```

The data is sorted by the Key field. Now, I want to compute an aggregate of the F2 field over partitions that are defined by the F1 field: A partition starts at the first X value and ends with the first subsequent Y value.

So, for example, I might want wo compute the MIN() over the partitions defined as described above. Then the result set would look like this:

```
rownum MIN(F2)  
1      4  
2      7  
3      3
```

I have tried a number of resources (incl. our own intranet community and of course stackoverflow) but found nothing for my case. Usually partitioning only works with a field that can be used to identify the partitions. Here, the partitions are defined by a change in a field's content with respect to a given order.

Although I am aware that I may have to resort to writing a procedural solution I would prefer to solve this in pure SQL.

Any ideas how such a partitioning could be achieved with a SQL select statement?

Thanks and regards
Kai.

Comment: Look at the [OVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) clause with PARTITION BY and GROUPING. I do not have access to a SQL-Server now, so can't test any code but it should be something like:
 select min(f2) over (partition by f1) as [minval]
 group by f1

Comment: @pasty if you don't have your sql engine available. Give sqlfiddle a shot: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit shorter solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7390d/24

**Query:**

```
select min(f2)
from t t1
group by (select max(key) 
          from t t2 
          where t2.f1='Y' and 
                t1.key > t2.key)
```

**Result:**

```
| MIN |
-------
|   4 |
|   7 |
|   3 |
```

The idea is to find the key of preceding 'Y' for each row and group by it. Should work with any SQL engine.

Comment: Thanks, Stas S - that's it for me!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify engine or dialect or version so I assumed SQL Server 2012.

Example that you can run to see the solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f5d38/21

You solve it by creating correct partitions in your set. Code looks like this.

```
WITH groupLimits as
(
SELECT
[Key] AS groupend
,COALESCE(LAG([Key]) OVER (order by [Key]),0)+1 AS groupstart
FROM sourceData
WHERE F1 = 'Y'
)
SELECT
MIN(sourceData.F2)
FROM groupLimits
INNER JOIN sourceData
  ON sourceData.[Key] BETWEEN groupLimits.groupstart and groupLimits.groupend
GROUP BY groupLimits.groupstart
ORDER BY groupLimits.groupstart
```